# Select from two tables by priority

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make my website content editable, but edited Items are only visible to the editor till edit gets verified by moderator. I save the new edit to another table now the problem is that I want to select all Items from default table but if there is an edit to an Item get it from this table instead of default table

```
select * from (
select * from items where name = @name and 
name not in (select name from edits where name = @name and ip = @ip)
union 
select * from edits where name = @name) tmp order by name
```

the problem is user may not edit all fields and I must complete these empty (or null) columns from the default table

Edit: in the other words I want to select from default table but replace the edited fields of all edited Items if the editors IP matches the current user

any Ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to keep it in one table and add a field that indicates the edit process?

Comment: but I don't want to loose old data as the edit might not be useful and moderator would need to reject the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that the strucutres of your tables like this :

```
edits (col1, col2, col3, col4)
items (col1, col2, col3)
```

You can use this code :

```
select 
   COALESCE(b.col1,a.col1) col1
  ,COALESCE(b.col2,a.col2) col2
  ,COALESCE(b.col3,a.col3) col3
  ,col4 col4
from
    edits a
full outer join
    items b
      on a.name = b.name
where a.name = @name
AND   ISNULL(@ip,b.ip) = b.ip
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: ip will never be null only it might not match the editors ip. and I want to do this only when it matches the editors ip

Comment: No need for FULL JOIN here.

Answer (score 0):

Outer join the tables and substitute values from items for the columns where there are NULLs in edits:

```
select isnull(i.col1, e.col1) as col1, etc
from items i
left outer join edits e
on i.name = e.name
```